# How do I allow my IP-to-username resolution script to be run more than once in parallel?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using a python script to do IP to username resolution.

The issue I am having is that the script doesn't support parallel jobs. If the script is already running in one place, running it a second time causes the script to fail.

I have read about multithreading, but I'm not sure how to adapt that to our script.

How can I get the script to allow running it multiple times at the same time?

Comment: I think it's not a problem of python multithreading, but I suppose this script lock some network resource like port, or something else. That is why when you run another script it is failed. But it is just suggestion. To get more issue understanding you need to provide script itself and error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the question and more specifics about your particular case, so more people with knowledge of this subject will see it. I also edited your question to include more paragraph breaks where there is a change in subject or thought, as well as removing some extraneous intro and "thanks!" type language, so it will be easier for someone with your answer to see the problem quickly. Good luck!